# Templated Lambda function with compile time constants

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

I got this piece of code ([split code](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/21/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/)) online to split strings in a pretty cool manner, but then I want to make it a little more generic and manageable. I have implemented a workaround passing it in through the input parameter as a templated class with constexpr, but I was wondering if anyone would know how I can make this work.

I made a lambda function that accept one compile time constant, and I am trying to call it. At the call site it is mistaking the template parameters as an expression trying to do the less than operator.

```
auto splt_val = []<char delimiter='\n'>(std::string s)->std::vector<std::string>{
              std::istringstream iss(s);
              std::vector<std::string> parm_data(
                 (std::istream_iterator<WordDelimitedBy< delimiter > >(iss)),
                  std::istream_iterator<WordDelimitedBy< delimiter > >());
              return parm_data;
};

splt_val<'\n'>("test"); //<-- DOESN'T WORK

splt_val("test");       //<-- THIS WORKS
```

Comment: Haven't seen this before. Is this a GCC extension? Is it in ISO C++ or proposed?

Comment: It should be in the spec; -std=C++14 is the compile knob I use.

Comment: Looks like it's probably coming in C++20 Not in current VS 2017 which is finally reasonably complient. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
splt_val.operator()<'\n'>("test");
```

yes this syntax sucks.

```
template<char delimiter='\n'>
constexpr auto splt_val = [](std::string n)-> // ...
```

this gives you the syntax you are asking for.  But it means that there is a different `splt_val` object for each template argument.

You could probably write:

```
splt_val['\n'_k]("test")
```

where we write an adapter, but it would be awkward.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.